# After build fails to do npm start. Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to the site and React.
I built a project in React that works, constantly working.
I wanted to upload it to firebase, that's why I did npm run build, I could not upload it to firebase, and now npm start does not work either.

It drives me crazy, this is the error I get:

Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

```
  3 | import App from './App';
  4 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  7 | 
  8 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  9 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

I think I accidentally did something wrong with npm run build, firebase init, or firebase deploy. This is probably something really small

the public/index.html:
I did npm run build - maybe I changed it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.10/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did not touch anything, everything worked great until I did npm run build.

Comment: Is your code under version control? If so, you can simply revert to the version before you ran `npm build`, which failed.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `public/index.html` ?

Comment: @emi yes, I added now

Comment: There is a `public/index.html` in your project (created with Create React App?). This is used as an entrypoint and gets built into `build/index.html`. It will include initial HTML code and some JS to download the rest of the app. The one you posted has nothing to do with it. Somewhere in your build process you removed it, or you are posting a wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `<div id="root"></div>` inside your `public/index.html`. This is the DOM element where the React initial component is mounted with `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`.

As an alternative, you can create that directly from the JavaScript code, but the above solution is the usual and easiest one.

Comment: I did not understand you, where to put you <div id="root"></div>?

Comment: Somewhere inside the `public/index.html` file, inside the `<body>` tag, wherever you want your React app to be mounted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you're right the problem was in `public/index.html`
By mistake when I did build - I ran it

Comment: Please, if this helped, mark this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was to run `npm run build` in public.
I switched to the previous index I had.

Firebase init should be done on the build folder and not on the public folder